# Extensions for VS Code not working when downloaded with wget or curl

Tags: curl, visual-studio-code, wget, unzip, vscode-extensions

On a remote machine I am trying to use `wget` to download extensions for VS Code. However, the downloaded files are always corrupt and cannot be used. It turns out that using `wget` or `curl` will retrieve files which are a bit smaller than using a browser, so it appears reasonable that they cannot be unzipped. The URL I have used for downloading is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/stkb/vsextensions/rewrap/1.9.1/vspackage

```
Downloads/tmp >ls -la
total 168
drwxrwxrwx 1 enno enno  4096 Feb  6 08:45 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 enno enno  4096 Feb  6 08:45 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 enno enno 85317 Feb  6 08:45 curl.vsix
-rwxrwxrwx 1 enno enno 85317 Feb  6 08:45 wget.vsix
BWP-181WD4:Downloads/tmp >unzip curl.vsix
Archive:  curl.vsix
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  curl.vsix may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of curl.vsix or
        curl.vsix.zip, and cannot find curl.vsix.ZIP, period.

Downloads/tmp >unzip wget.vsix
Archive:  wget.vsix
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  wget.vsix may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of wget.vsix or
        wget.vsix.zip, and cannot find wget.vsix.ZIP, period.
```

However, using a browser-downloaded file works just fine:

```
BWP-181WD4:Downloads/tmp >unzip ./browser.vsix
Archive:  ./browser.vsix
  inflating: extension.vsixmanifest
  inflating: [Content_Types].xml
  inflating: extension/CHANGELOG.md
  inflating: extension/images/logo.png
  inflating: extension/images/logo.svg
  inflating: extension/package.json
  inflating: extension/README.md
...
```

How come? The file sizes are clearly different:

```
Downloads/tmp >ls -la
total 256
drwxrwxrwx 1 enno enno  4096 Feb  6 08:52 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 enno enno  4096 Feb  6 08:50 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 enno enno 90035 Feb  6 08:49 browser.vsix
-rwxrwxrwx 1 enno enno 85317 Feb  6 08:45 curl.vsix
-rwxrwxrwx 1 enno enno 85317 Feb  6 08:45 wget.vsix
```

Is this related to how `wget` and `curl` retrieve files or how Microsoft serves these files?

Comment: compare the files byte by byte with `cmp` and see which bytes are missing. Maybe tell curl to treat the file as binary.

Comment: `cmp` says `curl.vsix browser.vsix differ: byte 1, line 1`. So it appears `curl` does not simply download a part of a file, but something completely different. How can I tell `curl` to treat the file as binary? I could only find `--data-binary` which only affects uploads.

Comment: if you look with `od -x` can you spot the possible cause of the difference in file size

Comment: I used `od -x` to convert both files and then used `diff` which shows that both files are completely different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The files downloaded with wget and curl are **gzip** files.

Change the filename to `vspackage.gz` and use `gunzip` to extract the vsix file

If you look at the response header in the browser you see they are gzip compressed.

Find a way for curl/wget to use the `content-disposition` and `content-encoding` of the response header.

Comment: Just to follow up- gunzipping works, but the resulting file is a zip- so you'll have to further unzip it

Comment: @giessel vsix is nothing but a file in zip format. You can just rename the zip into vsix and vscode can recognize it.